# Sharing assets between projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently in the process of reorganizing a rather large .net mvc project by splitting it into smaller projects, and I can't seem to find a simple way to directly reference some of the assets (js, css, view templates, etc) in the original project. Optimally, what I'd like to do is have a separate project (let's call it Presentation) to store any new assets for the application, and reference them as if it were another path e.g. ~/Presentation/js/example.js. I originally looked at creating a VirtualPathProvider to solve the problem, but I can't seem to get it to work the way that I'd like. Any suggestions?

**Update**

I think I'm overcomplicating the issue. The assets aren't the issue (I created an IIS virtual directory for those), it's the Views that are the problem. I'm trying to split the views into two different projects, but the view engine won't find the views in the new project. I'm looking at using precompiled views to solve that problem (e.g. [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/)), but I'm not sure if it's the right solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project folder and select "Add.." "Existing item". You can store all the scripts or files in a single, shared directory, but since they are source or content files they need to be added to the project that is using them, otherwise they won't be deployed.

Comment: I'd thought of trying that, but it isn't very optimal considering that I'd have to add references to every file individually. It also somewhat defeats the purpose of separating the assets into a new project when I'd just have to add them back into the original one.

Comment: You can edit your project file in text editor and copy/paste them if you are looking at a lot.